# Memory Mapped File Inter-Process Saftey

Tags: .net, mutex, semaphore, memory-mapped-files

In my system I have 2 processes (there will not be more than this to consider) Where one process will write a payload to a memory mapped file and the other will "eat" the data (take the data to be used clearing the memory mapped file in the process.

Normal for this type of shared data system I would consider using a mutex or a semaphore for safety although down to the simplicity of the system I believe there is very little change of having any collisions or races or other unwanted behavior.

I have detailed the process below but in short the first byte of a system is a lock that will show is the set is currently being written or eaten (to prevent the two happening at the same time). The writer will only write if there is no data (position 1 is empty) and the eater will only eat if there is some data (position 1 is non-empty).

[image: Process flow]

Can anyone illustrate to me where the risk around not using more robust security (semaphores or mutexs) could come up. my only thought is in the time it takes to write although as this is what is scanned for to initiate I would guess this is not possible unless MMFs write out of order.

*Disclaimer in practice I know you should err on the side of caution and use as robust controls as you can and there is little benefits from not doing so, but this is a personal project and I like to see how I can push things to deepen my understanding, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Because the process can be interrupted between `Is Lock Set` and `Set Lock`. You need to make those steps together be atomic.

Comment: @MattBurland So if I locked down the process around the `Is Lock Set` and `Set Lock` to make these two atomic then would there be any risk from other areas?